# how can I unstake EOS Tokens staked to others?

Tags: cleos, stake, unstake

[image]

I was able to change the staked tokens for my self but i can't find any tool to unstake some of the tokens staked to other (child) accounts that I created.

**how can I unstake EOS Tokens staked to other account?**

Comment: `cleos system undelegatebw`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use cleos to `undelegatebw`:

```
cleos -u https://api.eosbean.com:443 system undelegatebw youraccount1 otheraccount "0.1 EOS" "0.2 EOS" -p youraccount1@active
```

In which, `youraccount1` is your own EOS account name, `otheraccount` is the other (child) account name, `0.1 EOS` is the amount of EOS to undelegate for NET, '0.2 EOS' is the amount of EOS to undelegate for CPU, and `youraccount1@active` is the permission you are using for your own EOS account.